# Executing and object's method from EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

How do I call an object's method from EL?

Give the object:

```
public class TestObj {
   public testObj() { };

   public String test() { return "foo"; }
   public String someOtherMethod(String param) { return param + "_bar"; } 
}
```

and the obj is added to the pageContext

```
pageContext.setAttribute("t", new TestObj());
```

How would I perform the equivalent of:

```
<%= t.test() %>
<%= t.someOtherMethod("foo") %>
```

using EL?

Comment: For anyone else suffering the same silly mistake as me, note the round brackets for a method call as opposed to square ones for accessing lists, maps, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's supported since EL 2.2 which has been out since December 10, 2009 (over 2.5 years ago already!). EL 2.2 goes hand in hand with Servlet 3.0, so if you target a Servlet 3.0 container ([Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org), [Glassfish 3](http://glassfish.java.net), etc) with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` which look like follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

then you'll be able to invoke methods with or without arguments in EL in the following forms:

```
${t.test()}
${t.someOtherMethod('foo')}
```

Comment: Looks like my container is using Servlet 2.3. oh well.

Comment: So you're using for exampe Tomcat 5.0? It can also happen that you're actually running Tomcat 7.0 but that the `web.xml` is incorrectly declared conform Servlet 2.3 and thus Tomcat 7.0 would run in Servlet 2.3 fallback modus.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Method calls in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692615/method-calls-in-el) method calls in Expression Language are currently in JSR status and not implemented yet. What I use is JST facilities for JavaBean components to do some invocations. For example, if you modify your `test` method signature to:

```
public class TestObj {
    public TestObj() { };

    public String getTest() { return "foo"; }
}
```

You can invoke `getTest()` method with this syntax:

```
${t.test}
```

Now, if you need something more elaborate -like with parameter passing- you could use Custom Method features that EL offer. That requires public static methods declared in a public class, and also a TLD file. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/jstl-el.shtml).

**Update:**

As @BalusC states, later specifications now support method invocations. If you're deploying to a Java EE 6 compatible container, [this Oracle Site](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html) shows how to properly use the feature.