# Why is request.getParameter("...") not evaluated in <c:out> tags in JSP?

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags

Why does the request object `getParameter` method not work like `param.property`?

This does not work:

```
<c:out value="${request.getParameter('term')}" />
```

But this works:

```
<c:out value="${param.term}" />
```

What is the difference? Why is the request object not accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is implicitly available in JSP, and it's `HttpServletRequest`. It doesn't work because your expression can't be evaluated. `param` is different key used by EL to evaluate parameters from URL.

Comment: So calling methods with parameters is not valid syntax? The reason I ask is that I have called getter methods of objects, but have never tried calling them with parameters inside.

Answer (score -1):

It follows from Aaron Maenpaa's answer to [Method calls in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692615/method-calls-in-el) that JSP Expression Language aimed at keeping the presentation logic computationally lightweight for the server.